# Xcode 6.0.1 Minimum iOS deployment target

Tags: ios, xcode

I am making as iOS app on Xcode 6.0.1 with iOS SDK 8.0. On simulator front I can see long list back till iPhone 4s but deployment target selection till 6.0. I want to confirm my app will work on the iPhone4s and above versions.
I am noob to iOS so please bear with me.

Comment: You support versions of iOS, not specific devices (generally). The iPhone 4s supports iOS 5 up to (so far) iOS 8.1. Do you want to support iOS 7? If so, your app will also run on the iPhone 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Deployment Target is the minimum OS version you support. You must support all versions including and above your deployment target. So yes, not only will your app work with iPhone 4S and newer phones, but you actually *must* support those phones.